# unclear as to what submatch does in vim

Tags: vim, regex

Im unclear as to what the submatch({nr}) expression in vim does. The manual says the following:

```
submatch({nr})                      *submatch()*
    Only for an expression in a |:substitute| command.  Returns
    the {nr}'th submatch of the matched text.  When {nr} is 0
    the whole matched text is returned.
    Example:
        :s/\d\+/\=submatch(0) + 1/
    This finds the first number in the line and adds one to it.
    A line break is included as a newline character.
```

I understand what submatch(0) does, but what does it mean by the '{nr}'th submatch'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

{nr}th means {number}th.  In this case it would be the same as \0, \1, ... \9 when not using an expression in the replacement.  See:

```
:help /\1
```

Submatches are enclosed by \(...\) in the pattern. See:

```
:help /\(
```